# loop through list items using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html:

```
<ul class="lorem">
 <li>text</li>
 <li>text</li>
 <li>hello</li>
 <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

How do I loop through this using jQuery? Something like:

```
var listItem = nums.getElementsByTagName(".lorem li");

for (var i=0; i < listItem.length; i++) {
    // if current loop has text 'hello' do something
    if ($(this).text() == 'hello') {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: As you can appreciate, I am relatively new to JS and learning.

Comment: This `nums.getElementsByTagName(".lorem li")` won't work. `.getElementsByTagName()` doesn't accept a selector. This would have to be `.querySelectorAll(".lorem li")` instead.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName()`, as the name implies, wants a tag name, not a CSS selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In jQuery you'd use [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each):

```js
$('.lorem li').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'hello') {
    console.log('hello found');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="lorem">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively you could `filter()` the elements to find the one with the matching text without using an explicit loop:

```js
var $li = $('.lorem li').filter(function() { return $(this).text() == 'hello'; });
$li.css('color', '#C00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="lorem">
  <li>text</li>
  <li>text</li>
  <li>hello</li>
  <li>text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".lorem li").each(function(){
 
 if ($(this).text() == 'hello') {
       alert($(this).text());
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="lorem">
 <li>text</li>
 <li>text</li>
 <li>hello</li>
 <li>text</li>
</ul>
```